# Anaconda command prompt or conda commands not opening, because of this, I think anaconda navigator is also not working

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I noticed that I had 2 versions of python of which 1 I got from anaconda and the other I downloaded python via microsoft store. Today, I wanted to delete the python from microsoft store as I did not want them to overlap and I anyways had a lot of predownloaded packages on my python anaconda (also the microsoft store python does not let me open via file location directly which I find annoying).

Hence, before I do anything with the path variables and even before I deleted the original python, I was trying to open Anaconda navigator. For some reason, it was not opening. Hence, I went over to cmd, the one of anaconda and the normal one (does not truly matter) and ran the directory of which I had my anaconda python. `"C:\Users\faris\anaconda3\python.exe"`

For some reason it returned this:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\faris\anaconda3\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\faris\\anaconda3\\python39.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\faris\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00004530 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

C:\Users\faris>export
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am aware about environment variables and have had practically no problems in setting the normal python up. Hence, I did the same for here where I got the director of which the python for anaconda set and set it to both my user and system path variables under `Path` (I am the only one using this computer so does not really matter either way for me). However, it only substitutes the name of calling the `pyton` command with `"C:\Users\faris\anaconda3\python.exe"`. This is a problem as it practically did not fix anything, only made it under an easier to call name.

Interestingly, when I opened python.exe under the director of where it was (where I was previously referencing as a command) it works fine, however it did include this at the top.

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

Hence it tells me to perform the command of `conda activate myenv` where "`myenv`" is replaced with the directory path. HOWEVER, even running conda returns the very first output which has been the main of my problems - all of the problems just keep accumulating!

Does it have to do with defining conda as an environment variable or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so basically, my solve on this was to completely delete Anaconda - there were errors when it was interacting with the python evironment of which was downloaded via microsoft store. Never bothered to download anaconda back as I realize I don't actually need it, it is, at least for me, easier to not use it but instead make virtual environments on my own with venv. Also, not to everyone, download python by yourself via webbrowser and the installer instead of the one in microsoft store - it just makes it a hassle for other stuff like setting as path variable and whatnot